# Should I upgrade from .NET Framework 4.5.1?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

At work, I inherited a few WPF applications that target .NET Framework 4.5.1.
But .NET Framework 4.5.1 is no longer supported on any OS as mentioned [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework)

Our clients use Windows 7/8.1/10 and they all have .NET Framework 4.5.2 or above. Since .NET Framework 4.5.2 or higher versions are in-place updates for .NET Framework 4.5, the WPF applications all run fine.

Should I update the WPF applications to target .NET 4.5.2 at the least? Cost of update is minor development work but a lot of time doing regression testing.

Comment: Yes, try to update to the latest version and keep it fresh.

Comment: “Cost of update is minor development work but a lot of time doing regression testing.” Upgrade or not, you won't have any time on regression testing. Even though .NET Framework 4.x is in-place upgrade, compatibility issues are very common and only thorough regression testing can ensure your apps' quality.